# Erro no upload de uma página em html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servidor, filezilla

Boa tarde, estou com um problema quando vou subir uma pagina html no servidor, eu criei este projeto em mvc5 c# e uso o filezilla para subir as coisas no servidor quando, a parte que fiz foi um popup e quando clica no botão ele vai para outra página, no localhost ele funciona certinho, quando fui testa no servidor ele deu um erro

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

tradução: 
HTTP 404. O recurso que você está procurando ( ou uma de suas dependências) pode ter sido removida, teve seu nome alterado , ou está temporariamente indisponível. Por favor, revise o seguinte URL e certifique-se que ele foi digitado corretamente.

o caminho quando clico o botão é :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("TornarPagina", "Home")">
```

Tentei ver o caminho que faz e está certo, pois no localhost do visual studio ele encontra a página ja no servidor não.

Se alguém poder me ajudar ficarei muito grato. Obrigado.

Comment: Você está publicando este projeto local antes de subir pelo FileZilla?

Comment: não, porque depois que testei no localhost eu ja peguei fui la no FileZilla e ja subi ele ai ele da esse erro

Comment: E você está subindo ele onde? Em qual hospedagem?

Comment: Desculpa não sei te informar, e um site que trabalho e sou novo nesse ramo

Comment: você acredita que o erro pode ser oque ?

Comment: Acredito que você esteja publicando de forma errada, ou ainda no servidor errado. Por isso preciso de mais detalhes.

Comment: entendi, porque arrastei o arquivo de acordo que esta na pasta local mas o site você pode ver no http://homolog.abcdoabc.com.br ai você clica no botao do popup ai vem o erro

Comment: Onde está o botão de popup?

Comment: quando ele carrega a pagina ele aparece em cima demora um pouquinho, ai aparece para clicar aqui, ele fica em cima se descer o scroll não vai conseguir ver e tem um tempo que ele some